# Random Question Sequence From Array Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I have 5 arrays with 6 questions in each one.
I need the script to pick 2 questions from each array and create an `input()` function. The part I can't seem to think of is how to make an output for a correct answer for the questions. I understand how a specified input would work but what about randomized.

Comment: Providing the code attempt with your explanation will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
randomNumber1=***some generated number (0 thru 6)
randomNumber2=***some generated number (0 thru 6)

array1=['what is the meaning of life', 'how far away is the sun',...]
array2=['what did is your favorite color', 'how many pennies are in 1 dollar'...]
q1=array1[randomNumber1]
q2=array2[randomNumber2]

input1=input(q1)
input2=input(q2)

#stores answers in a dictionary
answers={q1:input1, q2:input2}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the random module has the function that you want.

But it is easy to build one if you like. Python is easy.

Does this work?

```
import random
from typing import Iterable

def get_sub_random_list(sub_length: int, iterable: Iterable) -> list:
    iterable_copy = list(iterable)
    result = []
    for __ in range(sub_length):
        length = len(iterable_copy)
        if length == 0:
            raise ValueError(f"the iterable should longer than {sub_length}")
        index = random.choice(range(length))
        result.append(iterable_copy[index])
        del iterable_copy[index]
    return result
```

example:

```
>>> get_sub_random_list(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
[5]
>>> get_sub_random_list(6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3]
```

The complexity is `O(n+m)`: n is the length of iterable, and the m is the the times of the loop.